# Multiple transaction management in Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

I am using `Spring 4`, `JPA` and `Hibernate 5`. I have a service as follows:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public methodA() {
  // do some stuff
  methodB();
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public methodB() {
  try {
    methodC();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // only log
  }
}


@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public methodC() {
  // do some stuff
}
```

What I want to achieve is this: when `methodA` is called, everything executed before calling `methodB` should be persisted, independently to what happens afterwards. For this reason I added `methodB`, the only purpose of which is to create a new transaction, so if the transaction of `methodC` rollbacks, the original transaction of `methodA` does not rollback as well. So to sum this up, I want the first transaction to commit and the second to rollback in case of failure. Note that `methodC` cannot be changed in any way.

This code however does not work and I still get the exception: `"TransactionException: Transaction was marked for rollback only; cannot commit"`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am using Spring 4, JPA and Hibernate 5. I have a service as follows:

So you're using three methods inside **same service**

This highlight is important because of how spring AOP works.

If you call method within the same class, then the other methods do not get proxied by `@Transaction` so they're still using the same transaction of `methodA`.
Therefore you will see exception when the transaction is marked as `rollbackOnly` by `methodB`

So to solve this: You have to move the method `methodB` to another service so it will proxy-able by Spring.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I moved methodB and methodC to another service and now I get a different behavior: the application hangs and a response is never returned. Note that both methodA and methodC update the same object and once methodA finishes it saves it and flushes. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: No exception occurs?

Comment: No exception exists. Based on the logs, I saw that the application hangs at the end of methodC when the object is updated. After experimentation, it seems that the problem does not occur when the @Transactional line is completely removed from methodB. Does this make sense?

Comment: Do you move B and C to another `@Service` or not?

Comment: One question: Do B and C access the same table as A?

Comment: Yes, B and C are in a different service now. It seems to work ok, but only when removing the @Transaction line from B. And yes, all methods access the same table.

Comment: AFAIK, it is related to transaction deadlock. I guess both A and B trying to modify same rows. Please post another question with part of your code. Tag me here, I will check it for you. It's too hard to debug without seeing the code

Comment: Yes, I know for a fact that they are trying to update the same row, I assume that's why the problem occurs. Thank you very much for your help!